# Cannot edit Google Compute VM in Console - get "Make sure all fields are correct to continue"

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-console

I was making small edits to the startup script of my Compute VM in the Console, without issue. Now all of a sudden I get this "Make sure all fields are correct to continue" banner that appears when I try to save. Even if I click edit, make NO changes, and try to save, the same banner appears. For some reason I can no longer make changes to this VM.  This is a VM that has been running daily without issue for over a year, with periodic edits to the startup script.

The message gives absolutely no specifics about which fields are the problem. And I don't think I actually changed any fields other than the startup script.

I searched online for this problem but have only found one similar issue but not for Compute. See https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Workspace-Q-A/Getting-quot-Make-sure-all-fields-are-correct-to-continue-quot/m-p/404955.

See attached screen shot.

Any ideas?[image]

Comment: 1) Your screenshot only shows the top part of the available options. 2) Open the browser debugger. Refresh the page, and try again. Monitor the debugger Console tab for warnings and errors.

Comment: you can clear the cache or try to use the incognito browser and see what happens.

Comment: We are three having the same problem with two of our vms. It started to do that November 3. Tested in Firefox and Chrome. They are also Spot VMs.

Comment: To further investigate your issue I suggest that you contact [support.](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub)

Comment: @JonB, thanks. Already done: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/256891023.

Comment: I can confirm this is their issue. Thanks for sending it to the tracker. I upvoted your issue. Should I also comment on it?

Comment: Yes, that would be great, @hanzo2001. I am really surprised that they have let it go on this long. It's quite a defect.

Comment: I'm also facing this bug. I'm surprised they still haven't solved this.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was fixed some time ago by Google as part of https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/256891023. Apologies for not mentioning this sooner. Thanks.

Comment: 2023-12-01 - It's still a problem.